# Only run JavaScript function once

Tags: javascript

When a button is clicked, I'm displaying an image (in a JS function) however the function prints the image every time the button is clicked. I want the function to run only once so that the image can only be displayed once. What do I need to add to my code to do this?

```
<button class="colour-btn colour-btn--3" onClick="showImage3()"></button>
```

```
function showImage3() {
    var img3 = document.createElement('img')
    img3.setAttribute("src", "")
    img3.setAttribute("width", "700")
    img3.setAttribute("height", "400")
    document.body.appendChild(img3)
}
```

Comment: How about to use a global variable to indicate if the image has been already displayed?

Comment: I see at least 3 options: 1. Attach listener in JS and then remove it after execution. 2. use a flag variable,once excecuted, set flag to true and then if function executes again check if variable is true or not. 3. after function execution, remove/disable the button from DOM

Comment: Alternatively, set the button to disabled in the event handler.

Comment: Use a data-attribute like `data-clicked='true'` and check that within showImage3(); on each call.

Comment: You can just set `myButton.onclick = ""` inside your event handler, too

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can redefine the function once it is run the first time so it only runs once.

```
function showImage3() {
    showImage3 = function() {};
    var img3 = document.createElement('img')
    img3.setAttribute("src", "")
    img3.setAttribute("width", "700")
    img3.setAttribute("height", "400")
    document.body.appendChild(img3)
}
```

Comment: This is such a terrible solution, tbh.

Comment: It answers the general question of how to make a function that can only be run once. Like it or not it solves the issue.

Comment: IMO, that's a dangerous way to write code, and irresponsible to teach others to do the same. My downvote is only one voice, others are free to disagree.

Comment: Clearly you have never coded in lisp! Redefining functions isn't dangerous at all, it is why we have functional programming, to simplify problems by passing around functions as data.

Comment: OP struggling with onClick !== experienced functional programmer seeking programmatic efficiencies in lisp.  That being said, functions being able to redefine themselves (causing innumerable side-effects) is not "why we have functional programming". In fact, it kind of breaks the whole immutability, no side-effects, and pure function tenets of functional programming...

Comment: Try reading the source code for CLOS, redefining functions is HOW you got OOP in the first place!

Comment: Agree to disagree. [Principles of Functional Programming](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application_development/9781786461483/1/ch01lvl1sec8/principles-of-functional-programming)

Comment: You do know that software would be useless if we only relied on pure functions. I/O is a side effect. Yes, this function mutates itself and produces an effect that not only doesn't cost you extra memory of storing an indicator but also frees up memory! That is GOOD code!

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`Element.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Parameters) with the option `once` set to `true`.

According to MDN, the option `once` is:

> A Boolean indicating that the listener should be invoked at most once after being added. If true, the listener would be automatically removed when invoked.

```
<button class="colour-btn colour-btn--3"></button>
<script>
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', showImage3, {once: true});
</script>
```

```js
function showImage3() {
    console.log("showImage3(); only called once");
    var img3 = document.createElement('img');
    img3.setAttribute("src", "");
    img3.setAttribute("width", "700");
    img3.setAttribute("height", "400");
    document.body.appendChild(img3);
}
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', showImage3, {once: true});
```

```html
<button class="colour-btn colour-btn--3">Show Image 3</button>
```

You can also use this utility `once` function that returns a function encapsulating the function passed in as its parameter and will only run it at most once.

```
function once(fn, context){
    if(typeof fn != "function") throw TypeError("fn is not a function");
    var ran = false, res;
    return function(){
        return ran ? res : (ran = true, res = fn.apply(context||this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
    };
}
```

```js
function once(fn, context){
    if(typeof fn != "function") throw TypeError("fn is not a function");
    var ran = false, res;
    return function(){
        return ran ? res : (ran = true, res = fn.apply(context||this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
    };
}
function showImage3() {
    console.log("showImage3(); only called once");
    var img3 = document.createElement('img');
    img3.setAttribute("src", "");
    img3.setAttribute("width", "700");
    img3.setAttribute("height", "400");
    document.body.appendChild(img3);
}
var showImage3Once = once(showImage3);
```

```html
<button class="colour-btn colour-btn--3" onClick="showImage3Once();">Show Image 3</button>
```

Comment: We can yet again thank jQuery for pushing the native APIs forward to become actually user-friendly :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var imageAdded = false

function showImage3() {
  if (!imageAdded) {
    var img3 = document.createElement('img')
    img3.setAttribute("src", "")
    img3.setAttribute("width", "700")
    img3.setAttribute("height", "400")
    document.body.appendChild(img3)
    imageAdded = true
  }
}
```

Should do it, presuming you don't mind using a global variable in your code. It's not best practice, but it is the simplest way to solve this quickly.